# Does every topological $n$-manifold ($n>0$) admit an embedding into $\Bbb R^{2n}$? If not, what $n$-manifold does not embed into $\Bbb R^{2n}$?

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

The strong Whitney Embedding Theorem tells us that every smooth n-manifold (n>0) admits a smooth embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$. Also, every topological $n$-manifold admits an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n+1}$ (Munkres' *Topology*. Exercise §50.7).

**My question now**: can this last bound be lowered to $2n$? And if not, which topological $n$-manifold isn't embeddable into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$? (Whitney's embedding theorem already tells us that such a manifold cannot admit a smooth structure)

Comment: There are knots in $\Bbb R^3$ that don’t have a planar embedding.

Comment: @Henno aren't knots just $S^1$ as topological manifolds though?

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti exactly, every knot is homeomorphic to S^1 and is therefore embeddable in R^2.

Comment: The answer to your questions seems to be positive by various comments spread here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059088/does-every-topological-n-manifold-n0-admit-an-embedding-into-r2n-if-not

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds whoops I copied the wrong link earlier. The answer is positive by comments here

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I looked through the papers suggested by the first link in Sergey Melikhov's comment to Andy Putnam's answer and I was not able to find the desired statement.   (The second link in Melikhov's comment seems to be broken.)   I guess the situation is that the embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ somehow follows from the theorems in the Bryant-Mio and Johnston papers, but this isn't obvious to me as a non-expert.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti I feel the same way. I dont see how this follows from any of the statements made in those papers. The commenters also didn't seem too confident in their ideas of proving this.

Comment: I don't think it's been formally proven but it's generally accepted as true.  Any counterexample would have to be non-compact and have dimension $2^k$.

Comment: @JohnSamples It seems strange that such a basic result (not basic in the sense of difficulty of proving) isn't written down anywhere...

Comment: It is known that smooth (or more generally PL) manifolds embed into $\mathbb R^{2n}$. See https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1971-157-00/S0002-9947-1971-0278314-4/S0002-9947-1971-0278314-4.pdf

Comment: I wonder why most of authors call this theorem a "hard theorem" while its proof is inside the Munkres' Book as exercise?

Comment: @C.F.G Munkres embeds into $\mathbb R^{2n+1}$. Here we consider $\mathbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: @LéoMousseau Yes, beware any people telling you that such an inherently attractice theorem is known and follows readily from known results.  So what, they could prove it in 2 or 3 pages and get a paper in the Annals - but they just don't have the time?  A bit suspicious . . .

Comment: @JohnSamples Can you provide materials which elaborates the statement you gave- that any compact topological manifold with dimension not a power of $2$ can be embedded into $\Bbb R^{2n}$

Comment: @IvinBabu: If you want references to the compact case, see my answer at the linked Mathoverflow question.

Comment: It's likely a wasted bounty. The result is known in compact case and, most likely, is not in the literature in the noncompact case. If one  wants  to find out, the best thing to do is to email Prof. Washington Mio (at Florida State University) and ask him directly. He is a coauthor of the paper Bryant, J. L.; Mio, W., "Embeddings in generalized manifolds," with a result closest to the OP, answering it in the case of compact topological manifolds.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks