Any $n$-toplogical manifold can be embedded into $\Bbb R^{(n+1)^2}$.
It is actually known that every $n$-topological manifold $M$ (that is, an $n$-locally Euclidean Hausdorff second-countable space) could be embedded into $\Bbb R^{2n+1}$ as a closed space. For this fact see the section on Munkres' book Topology about dimension theory. However, if I were at the place of only trying to justify the intuition that any $n$-manifold behaves like some closed Euclidean subspace, the bound could be even coraser and the proof should be much neater.
I had a luck to find the following result in the book Elementary Differential Topology also by Munkres(see problem 2.10 in the book)

Problem 2.10. Let $M$ be a $C^r$ manifold of dimension $n$. Prove that $M$ has a $C^r$ embedding as a closed subset of Euclidean space of dimension $(n+1)^2$.

I tried to prove it in the case of topological manifold, $r=0$. Let $M$ be any $n$-manifold and I know I could choose $n+1$ coordinate charts $(U_1,g_1),...,(U_{n+1},g_{n+1})$ covering $M$. Consider then a partition of unity $h_1,...,h_{n+1}$ on these $n+1$ open sets, respectively and define $$F:M\to\Bbb R^{(n+1)^2}$$by $$F(x)=\left(h_1(x),...,h_{n+1}(x),h_1(x)g_1(x),...,h_{n+1}(x)g_{n+1}(x)\right).$$One verifies immediately this map is injective and continuous. If $M$ were compact then this would be an embedding and the proof is complete. But if $M$ were not compact, I struggled to prove that $F$ is an open map onto its image. Is this even true? If not, how can I prove Problem 2.10 then in the case $r=0$?

You need to define a proper such mapping.

@TedShifrin Could you elaborate on "a proper such mapping"? Did you suggest I should verify the map $F$ is proper?

As for your actual question, you have to choose your charts $g_i$ much more carefully in order for this construction to work. Namely, assuming that each $U_i$ is closed, you have to take $g_i$ which is a proper map. Lastly, the correct terminology is "a topological $n$-manifold" or "an $n$-dimensional topological manifold."

"It is actually known that every $n$-topological manifold  could be embedded into $\mathbb R^{2n}$ as a closed space, while the proof is fairly non-trivial." - It appears to be unknown:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059088/does-every-topological-n-manifold-n0-admit-an-embedding-into-bbb-r2n and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds

The map you've defined surely will not be proper. But can you explicitly construct a proper map $M\to\Bbb R$ using your partition of unity (you will want to know each of your $U_i$ has compact closure)?

Also, I no longer have Munkres's Differential Topology book, but you should check his conventions: Does he intend that $r\ge 1$ throughout? I would expect so.

@TedShifrin Oh yes that is true on his book.
